# Getting snowsql bootstrap could not verify the signature error when initializing snowsql after successful install

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I installed snowsql-1.2.17-windows_x86_64.msi from the installer.  After install, I am getting the
below error when calling the below command. please advice

```
snowsql -a XXXXXXX -u YYYYYY
Installing version: 1.2.17  [####################################]  100%
snowsql bootstrap could not verify the signature for the downloaded file. This snowsql command is not legitimate code. Enable the debug log -o log_level=DEBUG.
Failed to download snowsql. Check network connectivity: 1.2.17
```

Comment: It looks like the downloaded binary is not valid one. Can you download it again and check re-installing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because SnowSQL is trying to automatically update to the latest version but the signature file is still from the installed version.

In your config file under options, add `noup=True` (default is `false` which means update when available), and try again. Haven't tested this, but I think you can also add an option on the launch like this:

```
snowsql -a XXXXXXX -u YYYYYY --noup
```

Based on  Nick's answer, this seems like a bug so let's hope we don't see these errors going forward.

Comment: Complementing the answer above, the right option is `--noup` in case you prefer to do it at the CLI level. Another way to work around this, is to manually specify the version, for example, `-v 1.2.16`. There's also a command to list all the available versions in case you want a specific one: `snowsql --versions`.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd as administrator. Execute the command:
***snowsql --noup***
Close the window and now run snowsql as administrator. It should open, show a bunch of options and close automatically. Your snowsql should run fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake reviewed the issue and found that the signature file was incorrect.  It has been replaced with a correct signature file and you should not see this issue going forward.